# How to create global static class

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have two **usercontrols**, one of them have the **dataset** and the another one, shows me the data in **textboxes**. Now I want to call `TableAdapter.Update()` from the second class. To do this I need create global static class, to acess Adapter which is included in first class, from second class.

Can someone show me a little example?

I was trying to make a **shared sub** and call `TableAdapter.Update()` from it.. but stuck on complete code.

Comment: You can create an instance of the first class to access it in the second to achieve that, but ensure that the first one's class is declared in **public** access-modifier.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to make `TableAdapter` static (`shared` in vb.net):

```
Public Class Class1
   Public Shared TableAdapter as new Adapter
End Class
```

Then you can call it in `Class2`:

```
Class1.TableAdapter.Update()
```

But, a better way is to not declare global variables, but pass a reference of `Class1` to `Class2` and call the appropriate property:

```
Public Class Class2
   Sub New (ByRef cls1 As Class1)
       cls1.TableAdapter.Update() ' or assign it to a property and call it somewhere else
   End Sub
End Class
```

Even better would be to use dependency injection to not tightly couple the two classes.

Comment: Or just pass the TableAdapter into the constructor of Class2, rather than the instance of Class1.  That achieves the decoupling too.  I also agree there are many 'even better' options - it seems as if a UserControl (UI, View) is containing a TableAdapter (business logic, Model), for example.  Refactoring that could also end up resolving this concern. But that's a whole separate topic.  =)